# Create Cart based rails app for e comerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, caching, redis, cart

I'm in the beginning of creating an e commerce app for small business using react and rails, the question that I have is if we want users to add items to cart without logging in what approach should I proceed with? Saving the cart without user details will result in a lot of stale data. So should I use cache or redis or any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Perform all your operations locally in the redux store and reflect backend only when needed to checkout.

If you want persistence as a refreshing or closing browser.
Add items to cart on browser local storage, it can handle hundreds of item data easily.

Example of flow (these item, cartItem and cart are js objects) :

item -> cart_item -> cart -> checkout -> login -> sync and validate -> perform create request.

If you insist on using Redis, create a WebSocket connection, and create a separate channel and store data there and using a delayed job close connection if the socket gets closed for a certain duration. My advice, not much to be achieved from there.